# Заливка SKShapeNode текстурой

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spritekit

Возможно ли залить SKShapeNode текстурой что бы она была в масштабе 1 к 1 и повторялась пока не заполнит весь SKShapeNode? Пробовал использовать `fillTexture`, но он просто растягивает текстуру, а надо что бы она именно повторялась, создавая бесшовную текстуру без масштабирования.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/man1/413642637ebd0b00fe2b

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko спасибо! Жаль только что на Swift, придется повозиться что бы на Objective-C переписать, ибо Swift совсем не знаю)

Comment: мне бы такие проблемы :) смотрите ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на обжС (помните, что это категория на `SKShapeNode`)

```
- (void)setTiledFillTextureWithImageName:(NSString*)imageName tileSize:(CGSize)tileSize
{
    CGFloat targetDimension = fmax(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(targetDimension, targetDimension);
    UIImage *targetRef = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, tileSize.width, tileSize.height), targetRef.CGImage);
    UIImage *tiledTexture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.fillTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:tiledTexture];
}
```

и на свифте

```
extension SKShapeNode {
    func setTiledFillTexture(imageName: String, tileSize: CGSize) {
        let targetDimension = max(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
        let targetSize = CGSizeMake(targetDimension, targetDimension)
        let targetRef = UIImage(named: imageName).CGImage

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize)
        let contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextDrawTiledImage(contextRef, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: tileSize), targetRef)
        let tiledTexture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.fillTexture = SKTexture(image: tiledTexture)
    }
}
```

Comment: Единственно я заменил первые 2 строчки на `CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);`, что бы текстура не ресайзилась под пропорции шейпа.