# Безшовная заливка текстурой несколькихх SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spritekit

Для заливки `SKShapeNode` текстурой использую данный способ: [Заливка SKShapeNode текстурой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568983/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-skshapenode-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Но появилась необходимость что бы при заливки отдельных `SKShapeNode` они заливались бесшовно относительно друг друга. Т.е. если несколько `SKShapeNode` стоят впритык друг к другу, то шва не должно быть видно.

Пробовал привязывать позицию текстуры к координатам shape и к размерам, но ничего толком не вышло. Может кто подскажет как такое реализовать?

[image: Пример]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807545/multiple-skshapenode-in-one-draw

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Вариант с соединением к сожалению не подходит, надо что бы они были отдельными, и в случае чего можно было перемещать по отдельности.. плюс итоговый размер может быть сильно большой, что выдаст ошибку.